# Can every triangle be divided into five isosceles triangles?

Tags: triangles, contest-math

That's my problem: Can every triangle be divided into five isosceles triangles?

I've got to give evidence why this is true or not true...

(sorry for possible language mistakes - I'm from Germany)

Thanks in advance 
Markus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize:

Hypothesis: Every triangle is "n-dissectable" (can be divided into n isosceles triangles) if $n \ge 4$.

Every triangle can be dissected into two right triangles (how?): by dissecting it along the altitude to its longest side. Each of these can be dissected into two isosceles triangles (why?): by cutting along the median from the right angle to the hypotenuse in each, giving a dissection of the original triangle into 4 isosceles triangles.

Now use induction on $n$ to prove the case that any triangle can be divided into 5 isosceles triangles.

To prove it draw a line from any of the vertex to opposite side to get triangles so that one of the triangles is isosceles. Consider the remaining triangle as the starting triangle and based on what we know about being 4-dissectable, that any triangle can be divided to 4 isosceles triangles, we get 4 isosceles triangles from this triangle, (the second of the two from the of original triangle. This gives us that the first isosceles triangle, plus the 4 sub-isosceles triangles combine to make any triangle dissectable (divided) into a total of 5 isosceles triangles.

An equilateral triangle can be dealt with separately: Cut off a small equilateral triangle from a corner (base parallel to to larger base), and since an isosceles trapezoid always has a circumcircle, one can obtain 4 isosceles triangles from within the trapezoind = total 5. [Alternatively, if you count the original equilateral triangle as a separate isosceles triangle, the proceed as in the case for $n = 4$ to obtain $4$ interior isosceles triangles, you have, in total, 5 isosceles triangles.]

The attachment can clarify matters further.

See [**Dissecting a triangle into 4 or more isosceles triangles**](http://cms.math.ca/crux/v22/n3/page97-100.pdf)

The above link goes into great detail and proves what you need to prove, and provides pictures that portray exactly what's going on, which might help, in terms of any language-translation barriers.

Comment: What do you mean by induction on n?

Comment: What do you mean by induction on n? My English is too bad to understand it -.-

Comment: We show the base case: n = 4. Then assume the inductive hypothesis, that we can divide any triangle into 4 or more isosceles triangles. Then we prove, using the base case, that any triangle can can be dissected into $n+1$ (in this case 5) isosceles triangles.

Comment: Ok thank you  :) could you just tell me how tho dissect a isosceles triangle into 2 isosceles triangles?

Comment: @user55214 You don't - you dissect your original triangle into an isosceles triangle $T_1$ and another (non-isosceles) triangle $T_2$, and then use the procedure outlined here to dissect $T_2$ into four isosceles triangles $T_{2a}, T_{2b}, T_{2c}, T_{2d}$.  This then gives you a dissection of your original triangle into five isosceles triangles: $T_1, T_{2a}, T_{2b}, T_{2c},$ and $T_{2d}$.

Comment: user55214 Do you understand now? I expanded a bit on my answer.

Comment: Actually, one question now that I look at this: what if the original triangle is equilateral, so that all isosceles triangles that you can generate from it in the subdivision step leave trivial 'remaining triangles'?

Comment: @ amWhy: Now I understand everything :) thank you

Comment: @ Steven Stadnicki: i think i got your point... if we start with a soscles triangle, how can we dissect the last remaining isosceles triangle into two isosceles triangles...

Comment: One can also start by dividing the equilateral triangle into 4 isosceles triangles, one of which can then be dissected into two isosceles triangles in the case of an equilateral triangle. The attachment can clarify matters further.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki The equilaterial triangle has to be dealt with separately. It's simple to do so, Cut off a small equilateral triangle form the tip, and use the fact that an isosceles trapezoid always has a circumcircle to get 4 isosceles triangles.

Comment: Can isosceles be declared the same as equilateral?

Comment: an equilateral triangle is an isosceles triangle

Comment: so it is true that we can devide EVERY triangle (even equiliteral ones and isosceles ones) into five isosceles triangles?

Comment: Yes, we can. Every one. And more (but not necessary for your question), we can divide EVERY triangle into $n$ isosceles triangles for every $n \ge 4$!

Comment: I'm just so curious about making that answer sure because i have to answer this question for a very important exam... So thank you :)

Comment: Your very welcome, uswer55214. It is good to want to be certain.

Comment: @amWhy $n=3$ is also possible. Choose the circumcenter. And join it to the vertices, the three triangles formed are isosceles triangles.

Comment: One more question: You say that every isosceles trapezoid can be dissectored into 4 isosceles triangles... But how? I don't get the point with it's circumcirle -.-

Comment: I just found the answer on my own :D pretty easy in german words :D

Comment: @amWhy Can you explain your equilateral triangle case? Assuming I'm reading you correctly, you're drawing an altitude to get 2 30-60-90  triangles, and then drawing the median to each get a 60-60-60 and a 30-30-120 triangle. Which one do we then dissect, and how? I can't seem to dissect either of them.

Comment: @user55214 The trick with the circumcircle, is that if you connect the circumcenter to the vertices, you will then get isosceles triangles all around. The only condition we need is for the circumcenter to be within the figure, to get a valid triangulation. This is guaranteed by making the cutoff equilateral triangle 'small', < 1/2 the original length will suffice.

Comment: @CalvinLin I deleted my answer because I went down your route of trying to dissect the $30-30-120$ but I couldn't figure out how to do it. In my answer, my justification for why you can 3-dissect a right triangle was because it was a theorem from my link... However, upon inspection, I'm not sure I can trust that information. I'll probably just leave my answer deleted and try and help with the accepted one.

Comment: So we do not really know how to 5 dissect a isosceles triangle? :/

Comment: Yes, we do, user55214.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to divide a triangle into five isosceles triangles. This is provable by induction. The fact that all right triangles are 2-dissectible is important because every triangle can be divided into two right triangles by cutting along the altitude to its longest side. Each can then be cut into two isosceles triangles by cutting along the median from the right angle to the hypotenuse.

Hence using this we can prove that any triangle can be divided to 4 isosceles triangles. Further we use this to prove that any triangle can be divided to 5 isosceles triangles.

To prove it draw a line from any of the vertex to opposite side to get triangles. One of them will be isosceles. Consider other as new starting triangle and based on above proved theorem that any triangle can be divided to 4 isosceles triangles we get 4 isosceles triangles from other part of original triangle

Hence giving in total 5 isoceles triangles. Please feel free to ask if you are little confused over this description.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer!!! I can mainly understand it, but as it's not German it's a little confusing ;) I will try to redo it on a sheet of paper and if there are any questions left I will just ask you :)

Comment: In the first paragraph, I think you mean "by cutting along the __median__ to its longest side". I do not understand what "To prove it draw a line from any of the vertex to opposite side to get triangles. One of them will be isosceles." means, but I can guess. You should elaborate more on it.